# Networkx's pagerank in Java (Eclipse)

Tags: java, python, eclipse, networkx, jung

I was looking through this page on how to summarize a text using cosine similarity: https://www.kaggle.com/neomatrix369/summariser-cosine-class. I stopped at the following three lines:

```
sentence_similarity_graph= networkx.from_numpy_array(sentence_similarity_martix)
scores = networkx.pagerank(sentence_similarity_graph)
rankedSentences = sorted(((scores[index],sentence) for index, sentence in enumerate(sentences)), reverse=True)
```

I have recently started learning and coding in Java, so my question is: Is there a way of translating these three lines into Java (assuming that we have the `double sentence_similarity_matrix[n][n]`)? I did quite an extensive search for Java libraries and I found JUNG2 but I am not quite sure on how to use it in a Java Project. Any help?

Comment: If you can express your question more specifically you may be more likely to get an answer.  It's not clear if you're asking how to use JUNG, or how to use Java's PageRank algorithm, or how to use Java libraries in general, or something else.

Comment: My apologies. My question is really as follows: how to implement networkx.from_numpy_array and networkx.pagerank in Java? The reasons why I mentioned JUNG is because I thought that it has similar built-in functions. JgraphT is another potential library.

Answer (score 0):

JUNG has a PageRank algorithm implementation, as well as a number of related algorithms: https://jrtom.github.io/jung/javadoc/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/scoring/package-summary.html

You should be pretty trivially able to build a JUNG Graph by iterating over the elements of your matrix/array and adding an edge for each (non-zero) entry; see the JUNG sample code for examples: https://jrtom.github.io/jung/javadoc/edu/uci/ics/jung/samples/package-summary.html